# Flash Drop Down Menus Not expaning outside of object tag

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

My problem is a lot like this:
[Can I make a Flash/Flex Drop Down Extend outside the flash object boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115316/can-i-make-a-flash-flex-drop-down-extend-outside-the-flash-object-boundaries)

Except I am not using `<iframe>` tags only `<object>` and `<embded>` tags and not using flex at all.  The banner I have been suing is 90 px in height and has to stay that way, which causes the problem of drop down menus being cut off when opening them.

Is there a way to make them extend out of the object tag, or even have them always extend down because currently they all want to extend up even though some could be seen better going down?

Answer (score 0):

If it's your site, then you can use Javascript to change the object's height.

Comment: Changing the objects Height does help make the drop downs show up but it will also move the actuall flash banner.